# How to turn off component block in joomla for certain pages

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have a page where it contains only modules.
So, I need to turn off component block in joomla for certain pages.
Is there any settings to turn off component in back end?

Can anyone help me out to fix this

Comment: you can either edit your template and check which menu item is active before loading the component block, or create an empty component without output

Comment: But if we change the menu name will that affect the condition which we use in the template file

Comment: if you change only menu name, it won't influence, since you would be checking for menu id in your template. you can even do it via template parameters for easier control

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "component block" but if I understand correctly what you need is [The advanced module manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/modules-management/10307)

It is free and allows you to assign things by owner, by pages, menus, components, by date, browsers and the list goes on...

Comment: component block is the class name of div where the component output is been displayed.Since I am using only modules to run a page,I got a empty box below the module and when I checked that in firebug add-on I found the div with this class name which has no data in it.That's why I am trying to disable the component for that page alone